# Bone index change after parenting

Tags: python, bones

I create an armature an all the bones through a script, then parent them. But the bones change the order in the list after setting the parents.

This script shows that each bone index changes after the modifying the parents

```
import bpy
import mathutils

print('HELLO')
#Clear all
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

#create armature
armature_da = bpy.data.armatures.new("Armature")
armature_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Armature", armature_da)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(armature_ob)
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = armature_ob


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

for i in range(10):
    bone = bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones.new(str(i))
    bone.head = mathutils.Vector((.01,0,0)) * i
    bone.tail = bone.head + mathutils.Vector((0,0,0.01))
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
print('creation',bpy.context.active_object.data.bones.keys())

print('first parenting')

armature = bpy.context.scene.objects.active 
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bones = armature.data.edit_bones
for i in range(9):
    editBone = bones[9-i]
#    editBone.parent = bones[9-i-1]   

#    editBone = bones[i]
    editBone.parent = bones[i+1]   

print('pre object',bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones.keys())
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
print('pos object',bpy.context.active_object.data.bones.keys())

print('second parenting')

armature = bpy.context.scene.objects.active 
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bones = armature.data.edit_bones
for i in range(9):
#    editBone = bones[9-i]
    editBone.parent = bones[9-i-1]   

    editBone = bones[i]
#    editBone.parent = bones[i+1]   

print('pre object',bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones.keys())
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
print('pos object',bpy.context.active_object.data.bones.keys())
```

Am I using a incorrect way to set parents?
Is there a way to preserve the bone indexes?

I am aware that I could use the names to reference the bones from the array, but I prefer to stick to indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't preserve bone indices, outside of edit-mode, bones are order by their hierarchy.

Its best to reference bones by name rather then index, *(Or at least get their index once, outside of edit-mode)*