# how can bone hierarchy change order? ways to preserve it?

Tags: python, animation

We spotted that in some of our characters, the bone hierarchy "changed". I personally would not know how to do that unless the bone hierarchy is recreated from scratch but I have to ask.

And btw, sorry in advance for asking this rather hypothetical question... but we have to fix this and I am wondering if we are doing it right.
So the question:

- Do you know what could cause this?
- Why/How an armature can change the order in the outliner and/or also in the `armature.pose.bones` array (not saying they are related)?

Thanks in advance

[image: bone hierarchy in blender A]

[image: bone hierarchy in blender B]

Comment: this is one way of course: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/bone-index-change-after-parenting?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outliner presents the bones in a hierarchy based on parenting to get the level of the bone in the hierarchy.  Obviously you can rearrange that by changing the parenting of bones.

The order of bones at the same level of the hierarchy is arbitrary from a user's view point and you can't explicitly control that.  It is initially the order that the bones were created in, but Blender might change it if new bones are added, existing bones are subdivided, or parenting changes.

For a given release of Blender you can look at the source code and deduce how the order is generated; but there's no guarantee that the source will remain the same between releases.

Comment: hey thanks for your comment. 
maybe you can elaborate on what you said?... if the hierarchy of bones at the same level is arbitrary and cannot be changed...  is there anything in blender that could change it? 
btw, the picture is not that important... just to illustrate the question...  but anyways, if you look at the pictures again `l_front_leg` and `l_back_leg` are at the same level of `body` in both pictures, not parented.
I apologize if pics are confusing...

Comment: @user2854611 sorry about misreading the screen shots. Pics aren't confusing, I just misread them.   I've clarified what I meant by 'arbitrary'.  I hope that helps.